# Find missing number

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

In below grid there are 2 numbers missing fill it with appropriate number .
[image]

Text version:

```
 69   10   13
192   ?    45
279   64   ?
```

**Hint** :

> You need to divide number with something to get required result .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> 19 and 29

Reason

> Divide the number in the 1st column with 3. The answer you get is then the sum of the number in the 2nd and the 3rd column. F ex, 69/3 is 23. 23 is the sum of 10 and 13. So with that reasoning the "?" in the middle should be 19 and the other "?" should be 29.

Comment: You are right :) well done